# Inconsistent outputs from Scala Spark and pyspark job

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am converting my Scala code to pyspark like below, but got different counts for the final RDD.

My Scala code:

```
val scalaRDD = rowRDD.map {
  row: Row => 
  var rowList: ListBuffer[Row] = ListBuffer()
  rowList.add(row)
  (row.getString(1) + "_" + row.getString(6), rowList)
}.reduceByKey{ (list1,list2) => 

  var rowList: ListBuffer[Row] = ListBuffer()
  for (i <- 0 to list1.length -1) {
    val row1 = list1.get(i);

    var foundMatch = false;

    breakable { 
      for (j <- 0 to list2.length -1) {
         var row2 = list2.get(j);
         val result = mergeRow(row1, row2)
         if (result._1) {
           list2.set(j, result._2)
           foundMatch = true;
           break;
         } 
      } // for j loop
    } // breakable for j

    if(!foundMatch) {
      rowList.add(row1);
    }
  }

  list2.addAll(rowList);

  list2
}.flatMap { t=> t._2 }
```

where

```
def mergeRow(row1:Row, row2:Row):(Boolean, Row)=  {
  var z:Array[String] = new Array[String](row1.length)
  var hasDiff = false

  for (k <- 1 to row1.length -2){
               // k = 0  : ID, always different
               // k = 43 : last field, which is not important

      if (row1.getString(0) < row2.getString(0)) {
        z(0) = row2.getString(0)
        z(43) = row2.getString(43)
      }  else {
        z(0) = row1.getString(0)
        z(43) = row1.getString(43)
      }

      if (Option(row2.getString(k)).getOrElse("").isEmpty && !Option(row1.getString(k)).getOrElse("").isEmpty) {
          z(k) = row1.getString(k)
          hasDiff = true
      } else if (!Option(row1.getString(k)).getOrElse("").isEmpty && !Option(row2.getString(k)).getOrElse("").isEmpty && row1.getString(k) != row2.getString(k)) {
          return (false, null)
      } else {
          z(k) = row2.getString(k)
      }
  } // for k loop

  if (hasDiff) {
      (true, Row.fromSeq(z))
  } else {
      (true, row2)
  }
}
```

I then tried to convert them to pyspark code as below:

```
pySparkRDD = rowRDD.map (
  lambda row : singleRowList(row)
).reduceByKey(lambda list1,list2: mergeList(list1,list2)).flatMap(lambda x : x[1])
```

where I have:

```
def mergeRow(row1, row2):
  z=[]
  hasDiff = False

  #for (k <- 1 to row1.length -2){
  for k in xrange(1, len(row1) - 2):
               # k = 0  : ID, always different
               # k = 43 : last field, which is not important

      if (row1[0] < row2[0]):
        z[0] = row2[0]
        z[43] = row2[43]
      else:
        z[0] = row1[0]
        z[43] = row1[43]


      if not(row2[k]) and row1[k]:
          z[k] = row1[k].strip()
          hasDiff = True
      elif row1[k] and row2[k] and row1[k].strip() != row2[k].strip():
          return (False, None)
      else:
          z[k] = row2[k].strip()



  if hasDiff: 
      return (True, Row.fromSeq(z))
  else:
      return (True, row2)
```

and

```
def singleRowList(row):
  myList=[]
  myList.append(row)

  return (row[1] + "_" + row[6], myList)
```

and

```
def mergeList(list1, list2):
  rowList = []
  for i in xrange(0, len(list1)-1):
    row1 = list1[i]
    foundMatch = False
    for j in xrange(0, len(list2)-1):
      row2 = list2[j]
      resultBool, resultRow = mergeRow(row1, row2)
      if resultBool:
          list2[j] = resultRow
          foundMatch = True
          break

    if foundMatch == False:
      rowList.append(row1)

  list2.extend(rowList)

  return list2
```

---

BTW, `rowRDD` is converted from a data frame. i.e. `rowRDD = myDF.rdd`

However, I got different counts for `scalaRDD` and `pySparkRDD`. I checked the codes many times but couldn't figure out what I missed. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this:

```
scala> (1 to 5).length
res1: Int = 5
```

and this:

```
>>> len(xrange(1, 5))
4
```

Comment: In Scala, you should use "until" to reproduce Python's "range":  

(1 to 5)   --> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
(1 until 5)   --> 1, 2, 3, 4